# How to define gradient color globally?

Tags: qt, colors, qml, gradient

I have Gradient in my QML as shown below example. Is it possible to define color "#1AD6FD" or "#1D62F0" globally in QML?

```
gradient: Gradient {
    GradientStop { position: 0.00; color: "#1AD6FD"  }
    GradientStop { position: 1.00; color: "#1D62F0" }
}
```

Comment: Sure you can just define it as a global property?

Comment: @xander how do I do that and how to use it? Can you give me an example so I can mark it as answer.

Comment: That depends on your QML and where you want to use you color, if it's just in one QML file you can just define it in the root item, I can write a small answer with an example.

Comment: no I have 3 qml page. And I have to set the same color for 3 pages globally

Comment: I've added a small example and ideas how you can access those values form multiple files, but that depends on your project I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define custom properties on any QML object like this.

```
Rectangle {
    id: root

    // you can define your on custom properties like this
    property color gradientColor1: "#1AD6FD"
    property color gradientColor2: "#1D62F0"
}
```

And then use it in any other item that has access to the object where it is defined via the id.

```
Item {
    gradient: Gradient {
        GradientStop { position: 0.00; color: root.gradientColor1 }
        GradientStop { position: 1.00; color: root.gradientColor1 }
    }
}
```

You could also define the whole gradient globally if you like to reuse that.

If you want access to the properties from other QML files there are multiple ways to do that. If you have access to the QML root object you can also access its properties from other files or you can define a global JavaScript library with some constants for color values, but not whole QML objects in there I think (only pure JS).

Another simple way is to define an independent QML object with just some global properties for your project and include that in your other QML files with just an id to reference it, that is maybe the easiest solution.

Just define an empty QML-Item with some properties like the Rectangle example above and include it in your other QML files like this

```
Rectangle {
    id: root

    // include your custom QML global item (GlobalProperties.qml)
    GlobalProperties {
        id: globalProperties
    }

    // then you can use it like before, i.e.
    color: globalProperties.gradientColor1 // color prop from your GlobalProperties.qml
}
```

Comment: Its working. One last thing. How to define an independent QML object with just some global properties for my project and include that in my other QML files?

Comment: Just like your other QML files, just use an Item as root context and include it in your other QML files, I'll add an example in my answer.

Comment: Added the example, I think that is easy to understand but you have to experiment a little with QML to understand it all. If you have more questions just ask.

Comment: gradientColor1 color works but overlaps the all other items in the page. :(

Comment: It does? If you have an empty Item that should not be visible at all, but you can try `QtObject` as the root type that might work if you just want some properties. At last you can always hide the included object if it interferes with your layout (usually it should not) set `visible: false` on the GlobalProperties object.

Comment: visible: false didn't work but I will check QtObject. Is it possible to define the color in main.cpp file in my QML project?

Comment: You can also define "real" global properties in C++ side of QML if you prefer that. The `QQmlEngine` has a global context where you can set properties with `engine()->rootContext()->setContextProperty` (you can get the engine from your view). Here some example: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qqmlcontext.html#details

Comment: You should try to avoid using cross-file references. Instead you should create a QML singleton, and import that to the file whre you need it. Nameresolution would be inefficent and the risk of shadowing high.